Does airflow DatabricksSubmitRunOperator support python wheel
I know we could submit a python wheel job through UI, but is that possible to achieve it with airflow DatabricksSubmitRunOperator?
For doc, it seems that only python_file supported, is there workaround to submit a python_wheel to run?
Thanks in advance.

First of all you need to store you wheel and your main into a dbfs location and then call it with your Airflow DAG as this example:
    new_cluster = {
    "name": "my_cluster",
    "spark_version": "14.3.....",
    "num_workers": 1,
    "autoscale": {
        "min_workers": 1,
        "max_workers": 8
    },
}


spark_python_task_params = {
    "new_cluster": new_cluster,
    "spark_python_task": {
        "python_file": "dbfs:path/to/your/main.py",
        "parameters": []
    },
    "libraries": [
        {
            "whl": "dbfs:path/to/your/wheel.whl"
        }
    ],
}


spark_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id="run_this_job",
    databricks_conn_id="databricks_default",
    dag=dag,
    json=spark_python_task_params)

